# Why does my touchpad fail on resume from standby?

Tags: 11.10, touchpad, macbook

On resume touchpad disables and a reboot is needed to re-activate.

Macbook Pro 6.1

Ubuntu 11.10 MAC 64bit

Suspend - ok

Suspend Resume - ok

However, on resume in the loggin screen my touchpad works, but after I enter my password and return to the desktop the touchpad fails. A usb mouse still works fine.

I have to re-boot in order to re-enable toe touchpad.

This was not an issue when I had Ubuntu 10.10 32bit installed.

The install was a fresh install.

The bcm5974 driver will not install, says codependency errors. I manually try to install all dependencies and I get this error:

E: hid-dkms: subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 10
E: bcm5974-dkms: dependency problems - leaving unconfigured

Thanks

Comment: I removed: Xf86-input-multitouch and bcm5974-dkms and hid-apple-dkms. On resume from suspend my touchpad never froze. Will continue testing. must be a bug in the driver.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the following: Xf86-input-multitouch and bcm5974-dkms and hid-apple-dkms. On resume from suspend my touchpad never froze. Leave only driver from install.

Hibernate can be iffy, but standby ok...